# how can use some(numbers) cores of cpu from all cores, with tensorflow attributes

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to use the university server for my deep code, all CPU's core on the server is 64 but I have to use just 24 cores to everybody can use the server too. I try to limit my CPU resource. I search all StackOverflow to find a solution but all suggestion doesn't work for me for example downgrade tensorflow and use

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, 
                        intra_op_parallelism_threads=ncpu,
                        inter_op_parallelism_threads=ncpu)
```

and some others solutions by using

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(numb)
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(numb)
```

I have to use TensorFlow version 2 or higher because I use 'kerastuner' package in my code

Comment: Which version of keras and tensorflow are you using?

Comment: thank you for your attention....... I use TensorFlow: 2.2.0 and Keras:2.4.3

Comment: I have tensorflow 2.2.0 and keras 2.3.0-tf and python 3.7.8 and have same problem like you, i try use tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(... but still not work.

Comment: yes exactly I try on tf:2.2.0 and keras:2.3.0 and use 'tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto' but not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Admin rights on the server and its running a Version of Windows, you can simply restrict the resources via the task-manager.

If you want to do it by code... It looks like its a bug in Tensorflow, which might be fixed, regarding to the [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29968) issue.

You might want to try:

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(2)
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1)
```

As this was reported working by Leslie-Fang. If this does not work for you, I guess your only option is to join the github discussion, until its fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my problem was solved, the problem for me was that I entered the same number for both set_intra_op and set_inter_op and it used all the cores.